# WPF: add several triggers make my Object properties to disappear

Tags: wpf, listview

i have `WPF application` and `ListView`.
Into this `ListView` i am add my object that contains several properties: file name, id and progress (column with simple `ProgressBar`).

So this was my `ItemContainerStyle` before try to add some `style`  changes like change the color when the mouse is over:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border
                 BorderBrush="White"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now this is my current state of my `ItemContainerStyle` after:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                      <Border
             BorderBrush="White"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="White"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So now what i want to change works fine but from any reason after add my object i can only see inside my `ListView` the item with only `NameSpace.Classname` and all my `Object properties` disappeared.
So what i doing wrong ?

This is how i am add my object via code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyObjectsCollections{ get; set; }

lvFiles.ItemsSource = MyObjectsCollections;
```

And i also try:

```
lvFiles.Items.Add(...);
```

Edit:

This is all my `ListView` code:

```
    <ListView Name="lvFiles" Margin="16,453,0,40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="White"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF15669E"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Grid Margin="-6">
                    <ProgressBar Name="prog" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                                 Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                                 Height="16" Margin="0" Background="#FFD3D0D0" Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=prog, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                <!-- file name column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="500" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />

                <!-- duration column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Duration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />

                <!-- packets column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Packets" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Packets}" />

                <!-- progress column -->
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="50" Header="Progress" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: Can you show the code-behind and the rest of the XAML for the ListView?

Comment: All my ListView code added, code behaind is also added (few minutes ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the triggers, it is the fact you are setting the ListViewItem appearance via a ControlTemplate - but then trying to set the ListView.View as a GridView - which requires data binding.

It looks like you're trying to remove the mouse-over visual effects and set a blue border visual on selection.

You can achieve this removing your ListViewItem template setter and moving the triggers to the ListViewItem level:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF15669E"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```